# SQL Server : select and add to new column of same table

Tags: sql-server, select, insert-into

Given that kind of syntax

```
SELECT 'all the left part of 'email' column before @'
FROM [dbname].[tablename]
```

How to insert the SELECT query into a new column called 'email_left'?

PS. for simplicity I do not show the long query after my select query.

Comment: a bit unclear... you want to add a new column based on .... existed values? please provide expected results.

Comment: yes adding a new table based on a existing column called 'e-mail'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is an update:

```
UPDATE x
SET    [new column created outside this statement] = 'all the left part of "email" column before @'
FROM [dbname].[tablename] AS x
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution - computed column

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table_name
    ADD column_name AS 'all the left part of ' + email + ' column before @'
GO
```

update -

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.email', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.email
GO

SELECT email
INTO dbo.email
FROM [dbname].[tablename]
GO

--CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX index_name ON dbo.email (email)
```